# Can u check if a minecraft server has whitelist enabled

Tags: python, minecraft

I am working in python and used a libary name "mcstatus" and got information of a server like player count, version. But now I was wondering if there is any way to check if a server has whitelist enabled without using the library "mineflayer".

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://openbase.com/python/mcstatus/documentation#usage), which has no mention of "whitelist," no, it is not possible to check this with `mcstatus`.

Comment: is it somehow possible otherwise

Comment: @Pfefan I have not do anything with mine craft so I am not sure, I just searched the documentation for the module you meantioned.

Answer (score 0):

mcstatus utilizes the [Server List Ping (status)](https://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping) and [Query](https://wiki.vg/Query) protocols to ascertain information from a Minecraft server. Neither of those protocols mentions whitelist.